# Comparison in pattern matching in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, compare, pattern-matching, ocaml, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to write a function `set` which changes the index `i` in the 'a array `a` to the value 'a `v` and raise an `invalid_argument` exception if `i` is bigger then the length-1 of the array.
I know that this can be done with if/then/else:

```
let set i v a = 
  let l = Array.length a in 
  if i > (l-1) then 
    raise (Invalid_argument "index out of bounds")
  else 
    a.(i) <- v
```

However I want to know if this can be achieved in a pure functional approach, using pattern matching and the OCaml standard library. I don't how to compare values inside the pattern matching, I get an error at the marked line:

```
let set i v a = 
  let l = Array.length a in
  match i with 
 >>>>>>  | > l-1 -> raise (Invalid_argument "index out of bounds")
         | _ -> a.(i) <- v
```

Is there a workaround to achieve this? perhaps with a helper function?

Comment: There's nothing "purely functional" about using pattern matching instead of `if` expressions. Neither of your functions are purely functional, in fact, for two reasons: 1. They use exceptions, and 2. they mutate the array passed to it rather than returning a new array. Both are side-effects, whereas in a pure, side-effect free, function the only effect of evaluating it would be a value computed solely based on the input arguments. That is, you should be able to substitute the function application with its returned value without changing the program's behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An if expression **is** a *pure functional approach*, and is also the *right* approach. In general, pattern matching has the purpose of deconstructing values; it's not an alternative to an if.

However, it's still possible to do this with pattern matching:

```ml
let set i v a =
   let l = Array.length a in
   match compare l i with
   | 1 -> a.(i) <- v
   | _ -> raise @@ Invalid_argument "index out of bounds"
```

**EDIT:** Apparently, `compare` can return other values than `-1`, `0` and `1` so this version is not reliable (but you wouldn't use it anyway, would you?)...

Or, more efficiently

```ml
let set i v a =
   let l = Array.length a in
   match l > i with
   | true -> a.(i) <- v
   | false -> raise @@ Invalid_argument "index out of bounds"
```

But then you realize that matching over a boolean *is* just an `if`. Which is why the correct version is still

```ml
let set i v a =
   let l = Array.length a in
   if l > i then a.(i) <- v
   else raise @@ Invalid_argument "index out of bounds"
```

Comment: `compare x y` is not guaranteed to return `1`  if `x`>`y`, it might return any strictly positive integer.

Comment: @octachron Edited accordingly. Is there a specific rule about which values must compare return? Because whenever I have used it, it always returned `-1`, `0` or `1`.

Comment: The specification is here: https://ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html#VALcompare

Answer (score 0):

[BlackBeans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73173378/15261315) is correct. But also know that pattern-matching in OCaml can take advantage of conditional guards when you want to place a conditional on a pattern.

Consider the following simple example.

```ml
type species = Dog | Cat
type weight = int
type pet = Pet of species * weight

let sound = function
| Pet (Dog, weight) when weight < 10 -> "Yip!"
| Pet (Dog, _) -> "Woof!"
| Pet (Cat, weight) when weight > 100 -> "ROAR!!!"
| _ -> "Meow!"
```

The patterns `Pet (Dog, weight)` and `Pet (Dog, _)` would otherwise match the same values (with the latter not binding a name to the weight).

An equivalent with if/else would look like:

```
let sound = function
| Pet (Dog, weight) -> 
  if weight < 10 then "Yip!"
  else "Woof!"
| Pet (Cat, weight) -> 
  if weight > 100 -> "ROAR!!!"
  else "Meow!"
```

In many ways which you prefer boils down to opinion, and which you feel is more expressive.